# Wordpress PHP command and ELSE IF problem

Tags: php

I am trying to show different messages based on user's custom field data. 'Site-access' meta field can be 0 or 1 and I was able to retrieve it for logged in user using

```
 the_field('site-access', wp_get_current_user());
```

Now I have to apply a comparison statement to this command based on retrieved data. Unfortunately it doesn't work within ELSE IF tags and I can't assign it to variable.

```
$access = the_field('site-access', wp_get_current_user()); 
if($access == "1"){ 
echo 'welcome'; 
} 
else { 
echo 'access denied'; 
}
```

**Working code**

```
$access = get_field('site-access',  'user_' . get_current_user_id());
$int = (int)$access;
echo $int;
if ($int == "1") {
echo "it's 1";
} else {
echo "it's not 1";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could work like this; but you need to use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()`, since the latter displays the field instead of returning a value.
See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was able to get the data using get_field and assign it to a variable. But still can't put it to else if.
$access = get_field('gym-access',  'user_' . get_current_user_id());
echo $access;

Comment: if ($access == "2") {
    echo "it's 1";
} else {
    echo "it's not 1";
}

Returns = It's not 1

Comment: I've converted data to integrer and now it seems to work! Thanks again, Chris!

Comment: Welcome, @JohnnyDark - this should be interesting for you:
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php